# Use MATLAB to prompt user to select a image file

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am trying to implement a function starting with prompting user to select an image and do some image operation. Here is my code:

```
[FileName, Path] = uigetfile ('*.bmp; *.png; *.jpg','Select the secret image');
secretImg = FileName;

R = secretImg(:,:,1);
G = secretImg(:,:,2);
B = secretImg(:,:,3);
```

However, this prompt me the error:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in main (line 16) G = secretImg(:,:,2);

It works with traditional method which specify the filename inside the code like this:

```
%secretImg = imread('Images/lena.bmp');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
secretImg = imread(strcat(Path,FileName));
```

**Full code:**

```
[FileName, Path] = uigetfile ('*.bmp; *.png; *.jpg','Select the secret image');
secretImg = imread(strcat(Path,FileName));

%// One alternative is to use `fullfile` as rayryeng suggested, 
%// secretImg = imread(fullfile(Path,FileName));

R = secretImg(:,:,1);
G = secretImg(:,:,2);
B = secretImg(:,:,3);
```

Comment: I would recommend `fullfile` instead of `strcat`.  `strcat` doesn't insert the directory separator in between the two strings.

Comment: Weird.  It didn't have it for me.  Ah well.

Comment: @rayryeng, i tried it and it worked well, i think it differs with the version. i'm using 2014a. if you don't mind, i'll add your suggestion in the answer.

Comment: @SanthanSalai - Nope never mind.  I just misread my output.  I didn't extend my window long enough to see the ending slash :P it's fine. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `imgetfile`. Unlike `uitgetfile`, `imgetfile` will automatically filter out non-image files.